# Asynchronous data in UITableView

Tags: iphone, json, uitableview, asynchronous

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"celluleConnecte";

    celluleConnecte *cell = (celluleConnecte *)  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        UIViewController *vue = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"celluleConnecte" bundle:nil];

        cell = (celluleConnecte *)vue.view;
        [vue release];
    }
    else {
        asyncImageView* oldImage = (asyncImageView*)
        [cell.contentView viewWithTag:999];
        [oldImage removeFromSuperview];
    }


    // Configure the cell.

    NSDictionary *dico = [self.pseudoOnline objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     cell.pseudo.text = [dico objectForKey:@"name"];
     cell.sexe.text = [dico objectForKey:@"sexe"];

    CGRect frame;

    frame.size.width=70; frame.size.height=70;

    frame.origin.x=5; frame.origin.y=10;

    asyncImageView *asyncImage = [[[asyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];

    asyncImage.tag =999;


    [asyncImage loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dico objectForKey:@"photo"]]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImage];

     return cell;

}
```

Comment: what's your question? How you could implement download the data asynchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because you downloading image right in cell, that is wrong. Create a new class of `UIImageView` and downloading photos there using `NSData`. There are many examples over the Internet. Here is first i found markj.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/asyncimageview.m

Comment: when you full up cells with this  `cell.picture.image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dic objectForKey:@"url"]]]];` the program are downloading image each time, so this is slowly. You have to do downloading asynchronically, and to do that you have to create a class which should loading  images, and initize it in cell.

Comment: it's ok now. It's works good but one more thing. When i scroll down i can see the image in good order but when i scroll up the images are not in good order. I have to wait 1 or 2 sec before good image come.